# How to clear field before entering input while using TextChanged?

Tags: c#, winforms

So what I am trying to do is to be able to continuously type into all of 10 text boxes. I start from the first one, then after 3 characters were typed change focus to next and after 3 characters were typed focus on the next.

I have done that part, but what if there is text already in second text box? I have tries Clear() but it creates a bug for which won't let me type more than 1 character.

So when all text boxes are filled with junk data, so when I start typing at first text box 123 then moves to second text box 456 third 789 ect. but while next field is cleared first.

I am trying to work with this:

```
    public PingIPRange()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        txtF1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(NextField);
        txtF2.TextChanged += new EventHandler(NextField);
        txtF3.TextChanged += new EventHandler(NextField);
        txtF4.TextChanged += new EventHandler(NextField);

        txtT1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(NextField);
        txtT2.TextChanged += new EventHandler(NextField);
        txtT3.TextChanged += new EventHandler(NextField);
        txtT4.TextChanged += new EventHandler(NextField);

        txtInterval.TextChanged += new EventHandler(NextField);
        txtRepeat.TextChanged += new EventHandler(NextField);
    }

    private void NextField(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtF1.TextLength == 3)
        {
            txtF2.Focus();              
        }
        if (txtF2.TextLength == 3)
        {
            txtF3.Focus();
        }
        if (txtF3.TextLength == 3)
        {
            txtF4.Focus();
        }
        if (txtF4.TextLength == 3)
        {
            txtT1.Focus();
        }
        if (txtT1.TextLength == 3)
        {
            txtT2.Focus();
        }
        if (txtT2.TextLength == 3)
        {
            txtT3.Focus();
        }
        if (txtT3.TextLength == 3)
        {
            txtT4.Focus();
        }
        if (txtT4.TextLength == 3)
        {
            txtInterval.Focus();
        }
        if (txtInterval.TextLength == 3)
        {
            txtRepeat.Focus();
        }
        if (txtRepeat.TextLength == 3)
        {
            btnPing.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this? It seems you're going to type in a bunch of boxes and then btnPing will be focused. Are you trying to set the ping results of something in all these boxes, and then have ping be called again?

Comment: @Ryan Ternier: Yes, I do want to enter data to bunch of text boxes and then focus button. As my code shows this works fine, but when there are data already in text boxes it won't work. I am trying to avoid button which will clear everything :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `Enter` event for the TextBoxes, and do a `SelectAll` on the text.

```
txtF2.Enter += SelectTextOnEnter;
txtF3.Enter += SelectTextOnEnter;
// etc.


private void SelectTextOnEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
  ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();
}
```

Also, your NextField method doesn't quite do what you think it does.  Make sure your controls `TabIndex` values are in the correct order, then try changing your code to this:

```
private void NextField(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (((TextBox)sender).Text.Length == 3)
    this.SelectNextControl((Control)sender, true, true, false, false);
}
```

It will choose the next control based on the tab order of the form.

Comment: @NewHelpNeeder No, keep the code you have, just add what I have to it.

Comment: No- this means whenever the field is entered into, the text is selected

Comment: @NewHelpNeeder Just to be clear, the Enter event is what happens when the TextBox gets focused.  By selecting the text when the TextBox gets focused, your key presses will just over-write what you have in there.  It think it does what you want based on your description.

Comment: This would work well. But is there something wrong with my code? I am having a problem which won't let me to jump to 4th text box and I can only enter 1 character in 3rd one.

Comment: @NewHelpNeeder Nothing wrong with what you posted.  Does the 3rd TextBox have MaxLength set to 1?

Comment: @NewHelpNeeder Thanks.  I updated my answer with the fix for your NextField code.  I didn't really look at it before, but that code would only work if all the text boxes were empty because you are only setting focus to the next control that does not have 3 characters, not necessarily the "next" control.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that setting the the textbox Text property to an empty string prior to calling the Focus method would do what you want.

```
if (txtF1.TextLength == 3)
{
    txtF2.Text = String.Empty;
    txtF2.Focus();
}
.
.
.
```